# Color values in flextable

Tags: r, shiny, flextable

I have a Shiny app in which you can display arrests in USA and arrests in one "reference" country. I must display the table in "flextable" format for aesthetics reasons.
What I want is to color in red the values in USA arrests table when it's superior to the value in the reference table for the selected country.

Here's my code :

```
library(flextable)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Hello!"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Choice of the country to compare data with ----
      pickerInput(inputId = "SelectCountry",
                  label = "Select a country",
                  choices = c(unique(reference$Country))),
      actionButton("goButton", "Go")
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: flextable ----
      uiOutput("tableau_ref"),
      uiOutput("tableau_USA"),
    )
  )
)                               


server <- function(input, output) {

tab_reference <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
    flextable(tab_reference)
  })
  
output$tableau_ref <- renderUI({
    htmltools_value(tab_reference())
  })
  
tab_arrests <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
    flextable(USArrests)
  })
  
output$tableau_USA <- renderUI({
    htmltools_value(tab_arrests())
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's my data :

```
dput(reference)
structure(list(Country = c("France", "Germany", "Italy", "Spain", 
"UK", "Ireland"), Murder = c(30, 40, 22, 45, 20, 12), Assault = c(200, 
150, 287, 140, 200, 120), UrbanPop = c(50, 40, 15, 27, 41, 45
), Rape = c(19, 20, 23, 23, 21, 74)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))

dput(USArrests)
structure(list(State = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", 
"Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois"), Murder = c(13.2, 10, 8.1, 8.8, 
9, 7.9, 3.3, 5.9, 15.4, 17.4, 5.3, 2.6), Assault = c(236, 263, 
294, 190, 276, 204, 110, 238, 335, 211, 46, 120), UrbanPop = c(58, 
48, 80, 50, 91, 78, 77, 72, 80, 60, 83, 54), Rape = c(21.2, 44.5, 
31, 19.5, 40.6, 38.7, 11.1, 15.8, 31.9, 25.8, 20.2, 14.2)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Here's an example of the expected output :
For example here the user selected "France" as the country and in the second datatable values superior to France's are in red.
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flextable::color` to conditionally set the text color. I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box option to pass multiple conditions for multiple columns at. Instead I use `Reduce` and `reformulate` (for the conditions) to dynamically set the text colors for your table columns:

```
library(flextable)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

server <- function(input, output) {
  tab_reference <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    reference %>% 
      dplyr::filter(reference$Country %in% input$SelectCountry)
  })

  output$tableau_ref <- renderUI({
    req(tab_reference())
    reference |> 
      flextable() |> 
      htmltools_value()
  })

  tab_arrests <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    req(tab_reference())
    
    flextable(USArrests) |> 
      Reduce(function(x, y) {
        rows = reformulate(sprintf("%s > %f", y, tab_reference()[[y]]))
        
        color(x, i = rows, color = "red", j = y)  
      }, names(USArrests)[-1], init = _)
  })

  output$tableau_USA <- renderUI({
    htmltools_value(tab_arrests())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but my example was wrong. I must see all countries in the first table, and in the second table I must have the data in red according to the input in "SelectCountry". I have edited my question, code and example.

Comment: That doesn't make a big difference for the code as only the table outputted in `output$tableau_ref` changes. The only thing you have to change is that you have to use `reference` in `output$tableau_ref` instead of `tab_reference()`.

Comment: I get the following message : 0: unexpected input
81:         flextable::color(x, i = rows, color = "red", j = y)  
82:       }, names(USArrests)[-1], init =_

Comment: Check my edit. Not sure why you are getting this error as the code works fine on my side.