# Color values according to conditions in R

Tags: r, flextable

I am new to R.
I have two datasets :

```
grades <- structure(list(Grade = c("9th Grade (Freshman)", "10th Grade (Sophomore)", 
"11th Grade (Junior)", "12th Grade (Senior)"), Read = c(13.2, 
10, 8.1, 8.8), Calculate = c(15.4, 17.4, 5.3, 190), Draw = c(9, 
7.9, 3.3, 50), Write = c(21.2, 44.5, 31, 19.5)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))

mean_grades <- structure(list(`Total USA` = "Mean", Read = 10.025, Calculate = 57.025, 
    Draw = 17.55, Write = 29.05), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

I would like to color in red values in the "grades" dataset when they are inferior to the corresponding value in the "mean_grades" dataset, and color in green when the value is superior.

However, the tables must be in flextable format.

```
library(readxl)
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)

flextable(grades)
flextable(mean_grades)
```

The exepected output :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrCxm.png)

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75938114/color-values-in-flextable/75938517#75938517) to your case you could conditionally color rows, columns or cells via `flextable::color`. Not aware of an easy option to achieve that easily for multiple columns and conditions but I might be wrong. Instead the code below uses `Reduce` to loop over the columns and uses `reformulate` to create the conditions:

Note: According to example the `Read` score for `Sophomore` (= 10) is smaller than the mean grade (=10.025) and hence it get's colored red.

```
library(flextable)

flextable(grades) |>
  Reduce(function(x, y) {
    rows_red <- reformulate(sprintf("%s < %f", y, mean_grades[[y]]))
    rows_green <- reformulate(sprintf("%s > %f", y, mean_grades[[y]]))

    x |>
      color(i = rows_red, color = "red", j = y) |>
      color(i = rows_green, color = "green", j = y)
  }, names(grades)[-1], init = _)
```

[image]